# How can I get rid of "New minor version of npm available" on using npm?

Tags: upgrade, configuration, npm

Every single time I use npm it asks me to upgrade its minor version.

For example spam that I received on upgrading mapshaper:

```
6 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 7.7.6 -> 7.20.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.20.1
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@7.20.1 to update!
npm notice
```

all of that is unnecessary for me and I would prefer to hide it (for funding messages see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972251/what-does-x-packages-are-looking-for-funding-mean-when-running-npm-install)). Especially "New minor version of npm available" as new version seems to appear [every single week](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm?activeTab=versions) (more often that I use npm)

I know about `npm config set update-notifier false` but it is a bit of nuclear solution, likely also major versions and serious security issues will not be mentioned.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this and how ?

Comment: @Vipulw As usual with `npm` - there is no reliable way to stop spammy notifications and get actually important ones. I think that I went for hammer and used `npm config set update-notifier false` and killed everything.